# First body column width can not be altered after setting scrollable to true in primeng table

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am using primeng to create a table. I cannot change the width of the 1 body column if scrollable table property is set to true.

Column width can be modified in following cases:

1. Scrollable is false.
2. Table row with colspan is removed.

tableData is an array of the following structure:

```
[
 {
  section: string, 
  subHeader: string,
  columns: [
             {
                index: number,
                items: [] // list of strings
              }
           ]
 }
]
```

```
<p-table
  [value]="tableData"
  [scrollable]="true"
  [resizableColumns]="true"
  styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines"
  scrollHeight="{{ scrollHeight }}"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: '225px'"></th>
      <th *ngFor="let headerItem of headers">
        <div class="p-grid p-flex-column p-ai-left">
          <div class="p-col">
            <div class="box">
           {{ headerItem.something1 }}
            </div>
          </div
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <tr *ngIf="rowGroupMetadata[row.section].index === rowIndex">
      <td *ngIf="selectedPersons.length === 2" colspan="3">
        <div class="p-text-bold section">{{ row.section | translate: this.locale }}</div>
      </td>
      <td *ngIf="selectedPersons.length === 3" colspan="4">
        <div class="p-text-bold section">{{ row.section | translate: this.locale }}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  style="width: '225px'">
        <span>{{ row.subHeader }}</span>
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let column of row.columns">
        <div *ngFor="let item of column.items">
          {{ item }}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue but to help we might need a little bit more info using stackblitz, codepen, etc.

After checking, I was able to change the width of the `<th>` inside of the header template with the code you provided. However, I could see that you cannot change the width of the `<td>` inside of the body template.

One way to go about fixing it could be to add a conditional colspan (to match  with your other table rows) to the `<td>` you would like to change the width of, and instead add the width inside of a div inside of this . For example, right now you have:

```
<tr>
  <td  style="width: '225px'">
    <span>{{ row.subHeader }}</span>
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let column of row.columns">
    <div *ngFor="let item of column.items">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You could try using this code below and see if it solves the issue on your end. If the length of selectedPersons is greater than 2 (in this case - equal to 3), make the `<td>` span 4 columns, and if not, make it span 3 columns.

```
<tr>
  <td [attr.colspan]="selectedPersons.length > 2 ? '4' : '3'">
    <div style="width: 225px;">
     <span>{{ row.subHeader }}</span>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let column of row.columns" [attr.colspan]="selectedPersons.length > 2 ? '4' : '3'">
    <div *ngFor="let item of column.items">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You might notice that we are using [attr.colspan] instead of colspan="" because colspan property binding and interpolation can only set properties, not attributes of `<td>`. Adding the [attr.] prefix just tells angular that it is an attribute rather than a property.

Good luck! If you need more help, just reply to my comment.